# Gerber Viewer With Good Measurement / Distance Tools?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, gerber

I'm trying to measure some trace widths using Camtastic in Altium.  I have to say, I really find Camtastic very finnicky when I try to zoom and pan.  The measure distance function (which I am trying to use here to capture trace widths for an RF system) I've never really liked.

I'm coming from a reasonable amount of skill with Solidworks.

Could someone recommend an alternative Gerber viewer (doesn't have to be free), that is not so finnicky?

I've used GERBV last time I was doing my Gerber-trace-ninja-fu, and remembered thinking it was better but I'd like something even easier.  I'm literally to the point of taking a screenshot and transposing this darn thing to Photoshop....

Comment: I use viewmate. And it is free. (Apart from the pop-up once a day :-)

Comment: @Oldfart, is their point to point measure distance function easy to use?  Like click one spot, click second spot -- a measurement appears?  The bar is pretty low here, but Camtastic drives me mad.

Comment: 1/ File->Import->Gerber. 2/ View->Distance->Distance measuement tool (Zoom in for greater accuracy.)

Comment: Yes it should be this easy...  Camtastic seems to have console where the measurement goes just to torture users. God help you if you use the mousewheel to zoom in on a document in Camtastic.  Page up / page down seems to not go insane though.

Comment: In Camtastic, keep one finger on the "End" key to redraw the screen as needed.

Comment: @The Photon -- you are like the wizard of Altium!  Do you have a consulting service I can call in for? ;)  Cheers.

Comment: Ha ha, there are a lot of people who spend more time in front of Altium than I do.

Answer (score 4):

I Like Viewmate. I always use it as the last check before my Gerbers go to the factory. Often I still find some detail which I had no seen and fix the PCB.

Load gerbers with File->Import->Gerber...
Then I select all the gerbers as a group.

I just found that 'd' starts the measurement tool (Despite the menu showing a capital-D)

Example below:

[image: Measuring vertical distance]

Comment: Heavenly compared to Camtastic!

Comment: +999, and an angle measurement to make sure you are measuring at 90 degrees!  This may be an old nag free version: http://www.laserlab.com/download_viewmate.php, I'm using it for my two single measurements I need.